# Adding MarkerCluster to Google Map, not appearing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add the MarkerCluster functionality to an existing Google Map with markers. Using the API instructions I attempted to add the simplest example to start. Unfortunately, it makes the map disappear.

I assume I'm placing the markerClsuter variable in the wrong place, but I can't be sure. My JavaScript is not good so it's a bit confusing.

Advance apologies for the long bit of code, but I wanted to provide as much context as possible.

Any insight appreciated.

```
function mainGeo()
{
     if (navigator.geolocation) 
        {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( mainMap, error, {maximumAge: 30000, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true} );
    }
    else
    {
          alert("Sorry, but it looks like your browser does not support geolocation.");
    }
}


var stories = {{story_Json|safe}};
var geocoder;
var map;

var markers = [];

function loadMarkers(stories){
    for (i=0;i<stories.length;i++) {
        var story = stories[i];

        (function(story) {
            var pinColor = "69f2ff";
                var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
                    new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(story.latitude, story.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map, icon: pinImage});
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<div >'+
                '<div >'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h2 class="firstHeading">'+story.headline+'</h2>'+
                '<div>'+
                '<p>'+story.author+'</p>'+
                '<p>'+story.copy+'</p>'+

                '</div>'+
                '</div>'

          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,this);
          });
        })(story);
    }
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
}



 function mainMap(position)
 {
       geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
       // Define the coordinates as a Google Maps LatLng Object
       var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

       // Prepare the map options
       var mapOptions =
      {
                  zoom: 15,
                  center: coords,
                  mapTypeControl: false,
                  navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // Create the map, and place it in the map_canvas div
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        // Place the initial marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: coords,
                  map: map,
                  title: "Your current location!"
        });

        loadMarkers(stories);

    }


  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: are you including the external javascript for the MarkerClusterer?  What javascript errors are you getting?  A link to a live map that shows the problem would be helpful.

Comment: No, this was the method described in the API. The site isn't live so there is unfortunately no link.

Comment: Where was this method described in the API (the MarkerClusterer is not included in the v3 API)? What example did you start from?

Comment: You might look at this [working example](http://violettefamily.org/Reunion2011Map.aspx), from this [thread in the v3 API group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/0dd6b08ff55ef298#)

Comment: This is what I used http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html. I'm going to review the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Working copy of ["simple" example using MarkerClusterer](http://www.geocodezip.com/MarkerClusterer_simple_exampleA.html), obviously doesn't include your data as you didn't provide that.

Answer (score 0):

When your map disappears, it is most likely because of a syntax error somewhere. Perhaps you missed a comma or a semi colon. When you edit a marker and the marker code is incorrect, typically the map loads and marker does not.

Also note that if you added new code to your Marker, the marker cluster and marker manager will also require changes to the core variable.

For example, when I decided to make a new function to have markers with labels, that made the marker manager not work for me unless I also added a new function for the marker manager.